# ToOADate(); Convert Julian Date Excel

Tags: c#, excel, datetime, ms-office, openxml

I am using OpenXML to read and excel spreadsheet and dates are stored as numbers.  As I understand this is a julian format and every where I google says to use ToOADate(); to convert these numbers to dates.

The problem i am having is ToOADate(); does not resolve in my compile.  I am using Visual Basic 2013, C# Asp.net MVC application.

It appears this is in the System Namespace, but I already have a using System statement.

I am obviously missing something very basic - can someone assist?

```
 var test = 41725;
DateTime test2 = test.ToOADate();
```

The compile error I am getting is

Error   4   'int' does not contain a definition for 'ToOADate' and no extension method 'ToOADate' accepting a first argument of type 'int' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Post your code and error also

Comment: Just added some example code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are converting numbers to Framework DateTime instances, it is likely you are after the **static** method on the DateTime struct.

```
        DateTime dt = DateTime.FromOADate(23456);
```

This method needs to be scoped to DateTime.  In my example, the result is 20 March 1963.

There is also an **instance** method on DateTime which does the reverse...

```
        double d = dt.ToOADate();
```

The result in this case is 23456.

Your code indicates that you are trying to call it as an **instance** method on a **int**, and this will not work.  The compiler is telling you that there is no such method on the int primitive.

Try instead...

```
 var test = 41725;
DateTime test2 = DateTime.FromOADate(test);
```

And you'll get 27 March 2014.